# How to read a GeoTIFF file and return in a specific datatype in R language?

Tags: r, types, r-raster, geotiff

I am trying to read a large GeoTIFF file (18000×18000×40) of unsigned byte data format in R by `raster` package. I hope to read it as `raw` datatype (unsigned byte) in R, which then will be process by `Rcpp`.

However, it seems that functions of `raster` package only return the data as `numeric`datatype (8-byte float)  that will exceed the memory of my machine.

Are there any approach can read the GeoTIFF file and directly return the data as `raw` datatype in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the data in chunks. For example layer by layer, but you could also read the values by block (a subset of rows/columns, but all layers) depending on how you want the data organized for processing. Then for each chunk change the datatype. See `terra::readValues` or the equivalent in "raster".

You can also have a look at `vapour::vapour_read_raster` and `vapour::vapour_read_raster_raw`